# Should I be worried about Plagiarism here?

Tags: copyright, internet

I run an online food blog.    In the website, I post modified recipes that I find, I improve them, and post them; with credit of course.   Does this count as plagiarism?  I want to make an eBook, is it sufficient to list just the sources or do I need written approval from them?

Comment: Plagiarism isn't a legal concept.  What you ought to worry about is *copyright infringement*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plagiarism is an academic concept, not a legal one. The issue you are concerned about is copyright infringement.

A work based off of another copyrighted work is a derivative work. This requires permission of the copyright holder. Simply listing your source and saying "[no crime intended](https://youtu.be/m-KLAqyUg20)" does not help.

However, [recipes are generally not copyrightable](https://www.cla.co.uk/blog/higher-education/copyright-recipes) (at least in the UK/US). This is because they are a list of ingredients and instructions which is not sufficient for a creative work. The presentation of the recipe can be copyrighted, as can any descriptive text surrounding it.

If you're just taking the actual recipe, making a better recipe from it, and presenting that recipe in a better way, you should be fine.

Comment: "presenting that recipe in a different, worse way" is also legally fine. Your readers might be unhappy though :-)